# Nested generics in Java: "? super C" does not match with "Object"

Tags: java, generics

I have the following Java code.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A<? super B> type1 = new A<Object>(); //compiles fine
        A<B<? super C>> type2 = new A<B<Object>>(); //throws a type mismatch error
    }
}

class A<E> {}
class B<E> {}
class C {}
```

My only question is: why do the types `A<B<? super C>>` and `A<B<Object>>` mismatch? `Object` is obviously a supertype of `C`, so I don't understand why the two types cannot be compatible like this.

Comment: With `A<? super B>` you are using a *raw type*. This *may* be the reason that the topmost statement compiles, although I'm not entirely sure about that.

Comment: Is this just some exercise for you to learn generics? `new A<Object>();` and `new A<B<Object>>();` don't look like how this should be done in practice.

Comment: @lealceldeiro Yes, I wouldn't use code like this in practice, this is just for me to learn Java generics.

Comment: lets suppose in `A` we have a `void method(E e) { ... }` if the declaration of `type2` was accepted, we could do `type2.method(new B<C>())`, but `B<C>` is not a `B<Object>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java Generics are invariant. If A is a subtype of B, List<A> is not subtype of List<B>.
In your case B<? super C> is not subtype of B<Object>. Wildcards should be used, i.e. A<? extends B<? super C>>

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I read through the javadocs after reading this answer, and I noticed that `B<? super C>` is actually a supertype of `B<Object>`. Therefore, the following code: `A<? extends B<? super C>> type2 = new A<B<Object>>();` compiles.

Comment: Right, my mistake as well. 'super' wildcards is contravarient. I'll fix it in my answer.
For extends wildcard this will work:
`public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B<? extends Object> type1 = new B<C>();
        A<? extends B<? extends Object>> type2 = new A<B<C>>(); 
    }
}

class A<E> {}
class B<E> {}
class C {}`